# Is there a way to compare and highlight differences between multiple csv files sequentially?

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie in the programming space and there is something that I need to do across multiple folders that I feel will be easier if I can code it out.

I have a folder containing 12 csv files which I need to run a comparison in python against a particular column in these files. The files contain common columns and data collected in the twelve months of the year (Jan-Dec). Is there a way I can compare the difference between January file and February file, then February file and March file, March file and April file....all along highlighting the differences and saving them in one dataframe, in python?

**The data is numerical and I would like to run this comparison across this specific column.**

Comment: It's difficult to provide help without knowing more details: can you give us an example of what data that column might contain? Is it numerical? Categorical? How do you want the difference to be displayed? The difference of means? Element-by-element difference? Etc

Comment: Sorry, the data is numerical and I would like to highlight any additions made in the files.

Comment: For displaying the raw row-by-row diff between csv files, the [`difflib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) in the standard library might get you started. I infer that each file is "cumulative" in that it contains all rows of previous files, plus some extra rows? E.g. `1.csv`: `[0.5, 1.2, 3.7]`; `2.csv`: `[0.5, 1.2, 3.7, 5.2, -1.1]`; `3.csv`: `[0.5, 1.2, 3.7, 5.2, -1.1, 7.5]`; and so on? Or is it something different?

Comment: There might be cases of some entries being removed, but I am more interested in the scenario you have captured above.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have an index column, then you can extract the insertions/deletions by comparing the indices of each dataframe (corresponding to each file). This, however, only works if you have an identifier that is unique across files; that is, a single observation or row will always have the same ID (value in the index column) no matter what file it is in.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def series_diff(series1: pd.Series, series2: pd.Series) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Compare two series via their indices, returning a table of differences.

    Returns the additions and deletions made to ``series1`` to obtain ``series2``.
    """
    added = series2.index.difference(series1.index)
    deleted = series1.index.difference(series2.index)

    return pd.concat(
        [
            series1.loc[deleted].to_frame(name="value").assign(action="deleted"),
            series2.loc[added].to_frame(name="value").assign(action="added"),
        ]
    )
```

For example, if you have the following files and want to compare the `target` column:

- `jan.csv`:

  ```
  id,filler1,target,filler2
  0,spam,0.6059782788074047,eggs
  1,spam,0.7333693611934982,eggs
  2,spam,0.13894715672839875,eggs
  3,spam,0.31267308385468695,eggs
  4,spam,0.9972432813403187,eggs
  5,spam,0.1281623754189607,eggs
  6,spam,0.17899310595018803,eggs
  7,spam,0.7529254287760938,eggs
  8,spam,0.662160514309534,eggs
  9,spam,0.7843101321411227,eggs
  ```
- `feb.csv`:

  ```
  id,filler1,target,filler2
  0,spam,0.6059782788074047,eggs
  1,spam,0.7333693611934982,eggs
  2,spam,0.13894715672839875,eggs
  4,spam,0.9972432813403187,eggs
  5,spam,0.1281623754189607,eggs
  6,spam,0.17899310595018803,eggs
  8,spam,0.662160514309534,eggs
  9,spam,0.7843101321411227,eggs
  10,spam,0.09689439592486082,eggs
  11,spam,0.058571285088035996,eggs
  12,spam,0.9623959902103917,eggs
  13,spam,0.6165574438945741,eggs
  14,spam,0.08662996124854716,eggs
  ```

Here the index column is named `id`. Note that `feb.csv` contains additional rows with IDs 10 to 14, while rows 3 and 7 have been removed with respect to `jan.csv`.

Let's load the files:

```py
jan = pd.read_csv("jan.csv", index_col="id")
feb = pd.read_csv("feb.csv", index_col="id")
```

And run the diff:

```py
series_diff(jan["target"], feb["target"])
```

```
       value   action
id                   
3   0.312673  deleted
7   0.752925  deleted
10  0.096894    added
11  0.058571    added
12  0.962396    added
13  0.616557    added
14  0.086630    added
```

---

If you don't have an index column, it becomes difficult to accurately identify differences: for instance, two rows with the same value(s) could either be the same observation or they could be different observations that just happen to have the same value.

If we assume that the order of rows isn't shuffled around between files, and that any additions are made at the end of the previous table, one idea is to compare the rows line by line with a text diff, e.g. by using the [`difflib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html), which will higlight additions and deletions.

```py
import difflib

print(
    *difflib.unified_diff(
        [f"{x}\n" for x in jan["target"]],
        [f"{x}\n" for x in feb["target"]],
        fromfile="jan",
        tofile="feb",
    ),
    sep="",
)
```

```
--- jan
+++ feb
@@ -1,10 +1,13 @@
 0.6059782788074047
 0.7333693611934982
 0.13894715672839875
-0.31267308385468695
 0.9972432813403187
 0.1281623754189607
 0.17899310595018803
-0.7529254287760938
 0.662160514309534
 0.7843101321411227
+0.09689439592486082
+0.058571285088035996
+0.9623959902103917
+0.6165574438945741
+0.08662996124854716
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback @Anakhand. However the code isn't yielding the expected results. I manually compared two files for additions and the results differed from what the code returns. How do I share with you a sample file to test this, because a typical file contains like 4,000 rows.

Comment: Glad to help. Can you be more specific about what isn't working? I suggest you include a concrete example of input and desired output in the body of the question. It doesn't have to be the whole CSV file, you could select just a few rows from each to make an example.